# Stored Procedure in Classic ASP

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I am trying to execute a stored proc from a classic asp page and I am running into several issues with how it is inserting.  I am trying to map posted form data to params in the stored procedure, which doesn't seem to be working. I had to convert everything to a varchar just for the insert to complete, and somehow there are "." being inserted at the end of some fields.  I have looked at this for hours, and can't seem to find the issues.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertLicenseFee]

    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @uid VARCHAR(255),
    @phoneNumber VARCHAR(255),
    @accountNumber VARCHAR(255), 
    @fedID VARCHAR(255), 
    @dateEnd VARCHAR(255), 
    @dateDue VARCHAR(255), 
    @nature NVARCHAR(255), 
    @dateStarted VARCHAR(255), 
    @dateDisc VARCHAR(255),
    @saleName NVARCHAR(255), 
    @saleAdd NVARCHAR(255), 
    @empCounty NVARCHAR(255),
    @basisReturn NVARCHAR(255),
    @bType NVARCHAR(255),
    @bTypeOther NVARCHAR(255),
    @grossFedReturn VARCHAR(255),
    @busiDeduction VARCHAR(255), 
    @netBusiness VARCHAR(255), 
    @notDeductable VARCHAR(255),
    @total VARCHAR(255), 
    @deductItems VARCHAR(255), 
    @adjustedNet VARCHAR(255), 
    @netProfits VARCHAR(255),
    @licenseFee VARCHAR(255),
    @interest VARCHAR(255), 
    @penalty VARCHAR(255), 
    @finalTotal VARCHAR(255), 
    @lessCredits VARCHAR(255), 
    @lessCreditRadio NVARCHAR(255), 
    @balanceDue VARCHAR(255), 
    @stateTax VARCHAR(255), 
    @capitalGain VARCHAR(255), 
    @operatingLoss VARCHAR(255), 
    @partnerSalary VARCHAR(255), 
    @otherItems VARCHAR(255), 
    @royalties VARCHAR(255), 
    @dividends VARCHAR(255), 
    @capLoss VARCHAR(255), 
    @otherNotSub VARCHAR(255), 
    @totalDeductions VARCHAR(255), 
    @countyWages VARCHAR(255), 
    @totalWages VARCHAR(255), 
    @signature NVARCHAR(255), 
    @title NVARCHAR(255), 
    @subDate VARCHAR(255)  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @subDate = GETDATE();
    INSERT INTO  dbo.LicenseFeeForm
            ( userID ,
              phoneNumber ,
              accountNumber ,
              fedID ,
              dateEnd ,
              dateDue ,
              nature ,
              dateStarted ,
              dateDisc ,
              saleName ,
              saleAdd ,
              empCounty ,
              basisReturn ,
              bType ,
              bTypeOther ,
              grossFedReturn ,
              busiDeductions ,
              netBusiness ,
              notDeductable ,
              total ,
              deductItems ,
              adjustedNed ,
              netProfits ,
              licenseFee ,
              intrest ,
              penalty ,
              finalTotal ,
              lessCredits ,
              lessCreditRadio ,
              balanceDue ,
              stateTax ,
              capitalGain ,
              operatingLoss ,
              partnerSalary ,
              otherItems ,
              royalties ,
              dividends ,
              capLoss ,
              otherNotSub ,
              totalDeductions ,
              countyWages ,
              totalWages ,
              signature ,
              title ,
              subDate
            )
    VALUES  ( @uid , -- userID - VARCHAR(255)
              @phoneNumber , -- phoneNumber - VARCHAR(255)
              @accountNumber , -- accountNumber - VARCHAR(255)
              @fedID , -- fedID - VARCHAR(255)
              @dateEnd , -- dateEnd - date
              @dateDue , -- dateDue - date
              @nature , -- nature - nvarchar(255)
              @dateStarted , -- dateStarted - date
              @dateDisc , -- dateDisc - date
              @saleName , -- saleName - nvarchar(255)
              @saleAdd , -- saleAdd - nvarchar(255)
              @empCounty , -- empCounty - nvarchar(255)
              @basisReturn , -- basisReturn - nvarchar(255)
              @bType, -- bType - nvarchar(255)
              @bTypeOther, -- bTypeOther - nvarchar(255)
              @grossFedReturn , -- grossFedReturn - VARCHAR(255)
              @busiDeduction , -- busiDeductions - VARCHAR(255)
              @netBusiness , -- netBusiness - VARCHAR(255)
              @notDeductable , -- notDeductable - VARCHAR(255)
              @total , -- total - VARCHAR(255)
              @deductItems , -- deductItems - VARCHAR(255)
              @adjustedNet , -- adjustedNed - VARCHAR(255)
              @netProfits , -- netProfits - VARCHAR(255)
              @licenseFee , -- licenseFee - VARCHAR(255)
              @interest , -- VARCHAR(255)rest - VARCHAR(255)
              @penalty , -- penalty - VARCHAR(255)
              @finalTotal , -- finalTotal - VARCHAR(255)
              @lessCredits , -- lessCredits - VARCHAR(255)
              @lessCreditRadio , -- lessCreditRadio - nvarchar(255)
              @balanceDue , -- balanceDue - VARCHAR(255)
              @stateTax , -- stateTax - VARCHAR(255)
              @capitalGain , -- capitalGain - VARCHAR(255)
              @operatingLoss , -- operatingLoss - VARCHAR(255)
              @partnerSalary , -- partnerSalary - VARCHAR(255)
              @otherItems , -- otherItems - VARCHAR(255)
              @royalties , -- royalties - VARCHAR(255)
              @dividends , -- dividends - VARCHAR(255)
              @capLoss , -- capLoss - VARCHAR(255)
              @otherNotSub , -- otherNotSub - VARCHAR(255)
              @totalDeductions , -- totalDeductions - VARCHAR(255)
              @countyWages , -- countyWages - VARCHAR(255)
              @totalWages , -- totalWages - VARCHAR(255)
              @signature , -- signature - nvarchar(255)
              @title , -- title - nvarchar(255)
              GETDATE()  -- subDate - date
            )
END
```

And the HTML for the execution and parameter building is as follows:

```
    Set cmdInsert = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        Set cmdInsert.ActiveConnection = Conn
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "insertLicenseFee"
        cmdInsert.CommandType=adCmdStoredProc
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@userID", adInteger, adParamInput, 255, cint(Session("uid")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@phoneNumber", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, (Request.Form("phoneNumber")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@accountNumber", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 ,Request.Form("accountNumber"))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@fedID", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("fedID")))
        IF Request.Form("dateEnd") <> "" THEN   
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@dateEnd", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, (Request.Form("dateEnd")))
        Else
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@dateEnd", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , "-")
        End If

        If Request.Form("dateDue") <> "" THEN
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@dateDue", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, (Request.Form("dateDue")))
        ELSE
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@dateDue", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , "-")
        End If 


        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@nature", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, (Request.Form("nature")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@dateStarted", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, (Request.Form("dateStarted")))
        If Request.Form("dateDisc") <> "" THEN
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@dateDisc", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("dateDisc")))
        Else 
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@dateDisc", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "-")
        End If

        If Request.Form("saleName") <> "" THEN
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@saleName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, (Request.Form("saleName")))
        ELSE
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@saleName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "-")
        End If

        If Request.Form("saleAdd") <> "" THEN
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@saleAdd", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Request.Form("saleAdd"))
        ELSE
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@saleAdd", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "-")
        End If

        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@empCounty", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255,Request.Form("empCounty"))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@basisReturn", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , Request.Form("basisReturn"))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@bType", adVarChar, adParamInput,255, Request.Form("bType"))
        If Request.Form("bTypeOther") <> "" THEN
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@bTypeOther", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , Request.Form("bTypeOther"))
        Else
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@bTypeOther", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "-")
        End If

        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@grossFedReturn", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("grossFedReturn")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@busiDeductions", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("busiDeductions")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@netBusiness", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("netBusiness")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@notDeductable", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255,(Request.Form("notDeductable")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@total", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("total")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@deductItems", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("deductItems")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@adjustedNet", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("adjustedNet")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@netProfits", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("netProfits")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@licenseFee", adVarChar,adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("licenseFee")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@interest", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("interest")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@penalty", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("penalty")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@finalTotal", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("finalTotal")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@lessCredits", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("lessCredits")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@lessCreditRadio", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Request.Form("lessCreditRadio"))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@balanceDue", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("balanceDue")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@stateTax" , adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("stateTax")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@capitalGain", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("capitalGain")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@operatingLoss", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("operatingLoss")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@partnerSalary", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("partnerSalary")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@otherItems", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("otherItems")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@royalties", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("royalties")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@dividends", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("dividends")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@capLoss", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("capLoss")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@otherNotSub", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("otherNotSub")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@totalDeductions", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("totalDeductions")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@countyWages", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("countyWages")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@totalWages", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , (Request.Form("totalWages")))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@signature", adVarChar, adParamInput,255 , Request.Form("signature"))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@title", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Request.Form("title"))
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.createParameter("@title", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Request.Form("title"))
```

If I take out the append for @title, which appears twice,  I get an error message stating "Procedure or function 'insertLicenseFee' expects parameter '@subDate', which was not supplied".

I am just lost as to what the error could be here. Would someone please help me out before I go nuts?  I know all the form data is being passed over correctly, as I can see all the elements and the correct values.

Comment: In the column list of your `INSERT INTO` statement, "interest" is spelled as "intrest". Is that a copy-paste error, or an actual typo? Have you tested the stored procedure in Management Studio?

Comment: Thats just an actual typo on the db field itself that I haven't bothered to fix till I get this SP working, I am aware of it.  The stored proc works fine if I run it in Management studio, the error is with the parameter building itself

Comment: Not an answer, but you're using `varchar` for dates?  *Bad* idea

Answer (score 1):

Your second `createParameter("@title"` is being passed into the SP as param `@subDate` - if you remove it then you'll be missing a param - hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the NamedParameters property of the command object to `True`.

```
cmdInsert.NamedParameters = True
```